# Is there an app that associates a certain action to an arbitrary NFC tag?

Tags: automation, nfc

I'm using the [NFC Task Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) for launching actions stored on my own tags. This works fine.

What I'm searching for is an app that associates a certain action with an arbitrary tag. An example: my company ID card has an NFC tag. This tag cannot be changed by me. But I want to activate the "At Work" profile when I scan that tag.

So, the actual action is NOT stored on the tag but on the phone and gets triggered by reading that tag.

Is there an app that I could use for that?

Comment: Old question, but [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) allows you to trigger actions based on a tag id. Note that it recommends against it due to some tags randomly generating ids - so if your tag is one of these them you might struggle regardless of what app you use.

Comment: @stripybadger hi, your comment looks like an answer. Would you consider posting it as a proper answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking at [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama). You can set actions based on conditions, and one of the selectable conditions is `NFC tag detected`. I haven't tried this myself yet, but the program is pretty well thought out. Highly recommended!

Comment: whoa! great! must have been introduced in the short past. Aside of the NFC functionality, it seems like Llama was the app I was actually looking for! You get the accept for this!